# Powershell - Parsing ATOM RSS file

Tags: html, powershell, rss-reader

[rss file example][1]

I am trying to parse an RSS file from a website. The RSS file has rss.channel.item etc. I am able to parse everything except "description". It keeps returning HTML tags, and I want to be able to get the text inside which contains who is it from, affected areas, and description of the event. I would like to format everything to show a proper heading, information, and so forth.

Any ideas on how to do this task?

Code:

```
cls
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "" -outfile c:\""
[xml]$content = get-content c:\""
$feed = $content.rss.channel
foreach ($msg in $feed.item) {
[PSCustomObject]@{
'Date-Time' = [datetime]$msg.pubDate
'Title' = $msg.link.InnerText
'description' = $msg.description.InnerText
}}
```

Example rss file:

```
<item>
<title>Account Management Planned Outage</title>
<link><![CDATA[https://*.service-now.*/sp?id=service_status&service=5569a0344ffe72487e415cd01310c72e]]></link>
<pubDate>06 Apr 2020 11:51:42 -0400</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">014451c11b0c54547746766dcc4bcb96</guid>
<description><![CDATA[<p><strong>People and Locations Impacted:     </strong><br />All students, faculty, staff at all State locations<br /><br /><strong>IT Service(s) Impacted:</strong>
<br />Enterprise Directory services: ldap.*.edu, dirapps.*.*.edu, and ldap-prime.*.*.edu. No outages will occur, but services will be restarted.<br /><br /><strong>Date and Time:</strong><br />Services may be affected from 05:30ET until 06:59ET on Tuesday, 04/07/2020.<br />
<br /><strong>Technical Information:</strong><br />This alert will be  updated as new information becomes available. State IT users can view additional details in ServiceNow.</p>]]></description>
```

Comment: What does this RSS file look like? Hard to help if we can't see the file.

Comment: The original RSS file starts with <?xml>,<rss>,<channel>,<title>,<url>,<description>

Comment: But, when using the above powershell lines, it only shows html tags and text inside of each area, for the description field. The html tags are <p><strong><br>"some text"</strong><br/>

Comment: The example is presented in the discussion/

Comment: You mean, [like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159262/parse-atom-rss-feed-and-remove-html-tags/61159840#61159840)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, it is only showing one single record. It should be able to show more records.

Comment: it is solved. Thanks

Comment: Mathias, how can I add two options, sorting the date column, and an option for shrinking and expand the rows where only shows the title.