# Power shell script to display the row from HTML table

Tags: html, powershell-3.0

Can someone help here on how to retrieve the data from the entire row of selected string from table in HTML

Expected output should be as below

Xxxx 1  line 0   N/A yes  date   Date  1111   2222

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the attached img for reference

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please explain in detail what problem are you experiencing, what have you tried so far and provide the necessary code as text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, if you see the attached pic, there will be a sample html code which had one row and td values of that row from HTML table. I would like to get the output Of that row as mention above and also would be great enough if you could tell me how to retrieve the data from one of the row which Actually required from the HTML table that has too many rows. Any sort of technique to use like selecting the string from the row to display entire row that finds the string ?

Comment: Any update please waiting for the power shell script

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post. it is probably what you are looking for....

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159262/parse-atom-rss-feed-and-remove-html-tags/61195451#61195451
```